# Yen (¥) symbol for backslash (\) in TexWorks

Tags: texworks

Hi I am running TexWorks 0.6.2 on windows 10. In my text editor ( of texworks) whenever I type backslash (`\`) it is replaced by yen symbol (¥). The code compiles normally and if I copy the code and paste it on notepad or some other editor it shows (`\`). I was wondering if there is some setup in TexWorks which is causing this issue. I don't have this issue on command prompt or any other editor.

Comment: the yen symbol is defined as the escape character for japanese implementations of tex.  i can't explain how the substitution is made when you use texworks, but it's definitely related to the japanese tex input convention.

Comment: @barbarabeeton This is not happening in any other editors or programs, it is just in TexWorks. Although it doesn't affect the code any way, but it just looks odd. I have installed TexMaker just to check if the same thing happens but there is no issue with TexMaker.

Comment: @Prem: Do you have different language supports installed with your keyboard? You'll note a keyboard in your taskbar (lower-left).

Comment: @Werner I have four languages installed... British English, US English, Japanese, Nepalese...

Comment: @Prem: Perhaps, when running TeXworks, the keyboard switches to Japanese. If you're not using the Japanese keyboard, you can remove it.

Comment: hi @Werner, Here is the bottom right snapshot of the screen when TexWorks is running. I use Japanese keyboard occasionally. Had the keyboard switched to Japanese, it should have typed everything in Japanese ( just not only the backslash\).

Comment: Although I can't give you a clear answer without detailed information on TeXworks setting, this seems to be a font glyph issue. Some Japanese Unicode fonts renders U+005C (REVERSE SOLIDUS) as yen sign because 0x5C in [SHIFT_JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) corresponds to yen sign. Using an appropriate font in the editor will solve your issue in this case, and I recommend you [Source Han Code JP](http://blogs.adobe.com/CCJKType/2015/06/source-han-code-jp.html) as a typewriter font if you really need to use Japanese characters in your document.

Comment: @yudai-nkt I don't use Japanese character in TexWorks documents... i use them in word or while chatting.  I just tried changing font to calibri and it replaced the Yen characters with \ thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you remember what font was used before you switched to Calibri?

Comment: @yudai-nkt it was MS Gothic by default

Comment: Thanks. U+005C in MS Gothic is displayed as a yen mark, so that was definitely the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since the OP's problem has been solved through the conversation in comment section, I'll post it as an answer. However, I doubt this question deserves an answer because it is more of a problem of font design than that of TeX/TeXworks and might be off-topic here. If this question should be closed and I shouldn't post an answer, feel free to let me know.

Some Japanese fonts, e.g., MS, Yu, IPA, and Meiryo, render U+005C (REVERSE SOLIDUS) as a yen symbol while yen symbol is assigned to U+00A5 and 0xA5 in Latin-1 encoding. This stems from the fact that the code point 0x5C in [Shift_JIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) means yen symbol. Developers of the fonts above decided to employ a yen symbol as a glyph for U+005C so that inexperienced users do not get confused with the change in the appearance of the character. Therefore, what the OP considered as a yen symbol is actually *a backslash that mimics a yen symbol* (ridiculous phrase but I hope you understand the meaning).

So, the solution to the problem is to use a font that renders U+005C as a backslash. Below is a list of monospaced fonts that cover Japanese characters and render U+005C as a backslash. The OP does not need a Japanese font in TeXworks, but I'd like to write down for the sake of completeness. The latter two links are unfortunately available only in Japanese.

- [Source Han Code JP](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-code-jp): based on Source Han Sans and Source Code Pro.
- [Migu 1M](http://mix-mplus-ipa.osdn.jp/migu/): based on IPA and M+.
- [Ricty](http://www.rs.tus.ac.jp/yyusa/ricty.html): based on Inconsolata and Migu 1M. You need to run a shell script to create Ricty due to lisence restriction.

Comment: on or off topic, this explains something that has puzzled me for a very lng time -- why japanese tex input uses a yes sign for the tex escape character.  so it's not really a yen sign at all -- it just *looks* like one!  thanks!